# selenium c# - How to get span tag text under a div

Tags: c#, html, css, selenium

```
<div id="targetSummaryCount" class="large-text" data-reactid=".0.0.0.3.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.$target_key_30.1.1.0">
<span data-reactid=".0.0.0.3.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.$target_key_30.1.1.0.0">0</span>
<span data-reactid=".0.0.0.3.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.$target_key_30.1.1.0.1">/</span>
<span data-reactid=".0.0.0.3.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.$target_key_30.1.1.0.2">20</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the '0' and '20' values from the above html, using the div id 'targetSummaryCount'. Is there any way to do this in Selenium C# without using xpath?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS selector:

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#targetSummaryCount > span"))
```

This would match all `span` elements directly under the element with `id="targetSummaryCount"`.

Comment: `.get(0)` would return '0' and `.get(2)` would return '20'.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the solution in Java. Please Convert it to C#

```
    WebElement divSummary = driver.findElementById("targetSummaryCount");
    List<WebElement> targetKeys = divSummary.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
    // For  getting first and last element
    targetKeys.get(0);
    targetKeys.get(targetKeys.size()-1);

    // For maintaining queue of elements with text 0 or 20
    HashMap <Integer, List<WebElement>> elementmap = new HashMap <Integer, List<WebElement>>();
    List<WebElement> webElements1 = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    List<WebElement> webElements2 = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    for (WebElement elem : targetKeys){
        if(elem.getText().trim().equals("0")){
            webElements1.add(elem);
        }
        else if (elem.getText().trim().equals("20")){
            webElements2.add(elem);
        }
    }
    elementmap.put(0,webElements1);
    elementmap.put(20,webElements1);
    // elementmap.get(0) contains all span tag under target Summary Count div tag
    // elementmap.get(20) contains all span tag under target Summary Count div tag
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the "0" and "20" with an XPath:

```
string value_00 = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='targetSummaryCount']/span[1]").Text;
string value_20 = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='targetSummaryCount']/span[3]").Text;

// or
var elements = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@id='targetSummaryCount']/span");
string value_00 = elements[0].Text;
string value_01 = elements[2].Text;
```

And with a Css Selector:

```
string value_00 = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#targetSummaryCount > span:nth-child(1)").Text;
string value_20 = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#targetSummaryCount > span:nth-child(3)").Text;

// or
var elements = driver.FindElementsByCssSelector("#targetSummaryCount > span:nth-child(odd)");
string value_00 = elements[0].Text;
string value_01 = elements[1].Text;
```

Comment: Is it possible without using xpath?

Comment: @Nandu PH, yes, you could also use a CSS selector. I've updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
        var spanCount = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='targetSummaryCount']/span")).Count;
        var myResult = "";
        for (int spanIndex = 0; spanIndex < spanCount; spanIndex++)
        {
            var spanText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='targetSummaryCount']/span[" + spanIndex + "]")).Text;

            if (spanText != "/")
            {
                myResult += "span:" + spanIndex + " spanText:" + myResult;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Fetching the span which is the child of the div having id `targetSummaryCount` and text as `0` or `20`.

```
var span_00 = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='targetSummaryCount']/span[text()='0']");

var span_20 = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='targetSummaryCount']/span[text()='20']");
```